# How to handle encoded image while fetching data from server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

[while I was trying to fetch an image file stored in a server, I get this type of response on my console. How to solve this error??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxVlA.png)

while I was trying to fetch an image file stored in a server, I get this type of response on my console. How to solve this error??

On console::
{data: '����\x02=Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\b\x00\x05\x01\x12\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x011\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00J\x012\x00\x02…\x12���6�_�\x1At]��Q\x029�\r�,=?\n.>�\x10��+�2���%\x14Q^�\x01E\x14V�c3��', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}